# Code First EF relationship duplicate

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-relationship

I have a working model, but have noticed that the relationship has been created twice in the database. Originally, it created two columns in the table, but with the addition of a specified foreign key attribute it has now just the one.

I have an Account class, which has many employers who can use the account. (one to many) Here are the classes:

```
public class Account
{
    public int AccountId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = Constants.ValidationMessages.FieldRequired)]
    public string  Name { get; set; }

    public int? PrimaryUserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PrimaryUserId")]
    public Employer PrimaryUser { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EmpAccountId")]
    public ICollection<Employer> Employers { get; set; }

}
```

here is the inherited Employer class

```
public class Employer : User
{
    public Employer()
    {
        DepartmentsToPost = new Collection<Department>();
        Contacts = new Collection<Contact>();
    }

    [Display(Name = "Workplaces to advertise jobs")]
    public virtual ICollection<Department> DepartmentsToPost { get; set; }

    public int EmpAccountId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EmpAccountId")]
    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }

    public override string UserType
    {
        get { return "Employer"; }
    }
}
```

User Table:

```
UserId
Username
FirstName     
Surname 
EmpAccountId
Discriminator
```

Account Table

```
AccountId
Name
PrimaryUserId
```

There is one link back to the User table - this is for the `PrimaryUser` field, and this is correct. There are two other relationships: Account -> Employers. EF has named them `Account_Employers` and `Employer_Account`. These are duplicates.

How can I prevent this occuring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Employers` collection should be decorated with [InversePropertyAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.inversepropertyattribute%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) to point to the navigational property on the other side.

```
public class Account
{
    public int AccountId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = Constants.ValidationMessages.FieldRequired)]
    public string  Name { get; set; }

    public int? PrimaryUserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PrimaryUserId")]
    public Employer PrimaryUser { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Account")]
    public ICollection<Employer> Employers { get; set; }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I had just done that as a test. Glad to have my findings confirmed as the right answer!

Comment: Simon, if answer is good consider upvoting it, not just accepting it.

Comment: I can't upvote until 15 reputation... else I would very much like to. Sorry!